# Passing props with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I'm still learning React, but I feel like I understand at least the "basics". However, Routing with React router and just general "architecture" is where I'm getting a little lost at.

I'm making a personal project app, but ill keep my descriptions/components generic for the explanation. Essentially I have 3 Main components right now:

`<Table/>` (Rendered in "App" and also the main `/` URL route, it's essentially just a bootstrap table. Also contains my `state` which is an array of objects (That will be eventually retrieved via JSON via a `GET` request to an API)

`<Row/>` (A single row of data on the table, represented by 1 object in the array of objects from the state provided in `<Table/>`. Also contains a button that takes you to the "View" page/component below)

`<View/>` (What is going to be a "View/Details" page for the Row)

So I imagine my route for `<View/>` is going to be something like `<Route path="/:id/view" children={<View/>} />` (Keeping it super simple and generic right now just for the explanation)

Sidenote: How come sometimes I see `<Route>` wrapping a component and sometimes I see `<Route>` defined with the `children` prop pointing at the Component to render?)

Anyways...the button in `<Row/>` will be a `<Link to={'{$props.id}/view'}>` I think....however how exactly do I pass the props down to `<View/>` based on the `:id` param? I need to pass the data I receive in the `<Row/>` component onto the `<View/>` component (Because within the `<Row/>` component is where I link to `<View/>`.

I suppose ONE option would be to do something like `let {id} = useParams();` and then do a GET request specific for that particular resource from the API. But considering I'm already passing the data down to each row and it's available in the state within `<Table/>` it seems like an unnecessary HTTP request.

Im probably making this more complex than I need to, but I need to pass the "data" all the way down from `<Table/>` to the `<View/>` component depending on the data `id`. And I'm not really sure how to set up React router to do that. Hopefully what I'm asking makes sense.

Comment: Yes, `useParams` hook will get your route parameters. To answer the other question(s) about passing "data" on to children components it may be more helpful if you share your code so we have a better idea of app structure.

Comment: I ended up passing state in the `<Link to`> however it complains about not knowing anything about `props.location` in the view (despite redirecting to that page successfully and showing the component successfully)....did something change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, I'll reference the [react-router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) as this is answered in the subsection named ["route render methods"](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods).

The tldr of the above is simply that the "preferred" method of rendering components via `<Route/>` is by supplying actual children to the component. However, there are other methods and specific use cases that go along with each.

As for the core issue you're asking about: What you'll want to do is use an object in the `<Link />` component that persists a state to the `<View />` element that has all of the information that it will need. You can find react-router's documentation on this [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object).

Comment: I've been told that passing state in "Link" is "bad practice". Is there any reason I would NOT want to do that? (Outside of using some sort of global state or redux?)

Comment: Does the component that "Link" to have to be a class? Despite passing a state within the Link it says that "props.location" is undefined when I attempt to redirect.

Edit: Weird...when I used the `component={View}` in Route it works, but not when the component is a child...odd.

Comment: Been told that it's bad practice by who? I'd like to hear their thoughts on why they believe that in order to give my personal opinion on that. From my understanding, using the state value in this way is exactly for this use case (where you're not wanting to unnecessarily make additional HTTP requests).

Comment: Any idea why it only works when I use the `component={View}` prop for Link? and Not using it as a child of Link?

Comment: I've found nothing in the documentation that would explain that. The only difference between the two should just be that an element rendered via the `children` prop will render regardless of a match, while the `component` element will only render if the URL matches.

Comment: Sorry I meant not using literally the children prop but nesting the component between two Link tags.

Comment: My understanding is that this method should be the same as supplying a children prop, so unfortunately I can't answer that.